# C++ - How do you create multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to create a multidimensional array. What's wrong with this code?

```
int sorted_array[] = {{2, 3}, 5, 7};
```

It's giving me this error.

```
error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'int'
```

Thanks.

Comment: In c++ you don't use raw arrays usually. A multidimensional array in c++ should be `std::array<std::array<int, DIM1>,DIM2> sorted_array;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When declaring multidimensional arrays, all the dimensions except the first one must be specified.

e.g.

```
int sorted_array[][2] = {{2, 3}, {5}, {7}};
```

which is equivalent to :

```
int sorted_array[3][2] = {{2, 3}, {5}, {7}};
```

You cannot use:

```
int sorted_array[][] = {{2, 3}, {5}, {7}};
```

and expect the compiler to deduce `2` for the second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of creating multidimensional arrays:

```
int sorted_array[2][2] = {{2,3},{5,7}};
```

this creates an array that stores 2 arrays of int that store 2 integers

but i would recomend a vector

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<int> > sorted_array = {{2,3},{5,7}};
```

this is the same thing but vector has more function

you can access them both the same way:

```
sorted_array[0][1] = 3;
```

Comment: Worth to mention `std::array` should be used for fixed dimensions when these are known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct of course, but it's worth mentioning that a convenient way to create a 2D array is to wrap a flat row-major `std::vector` in a class as follows:

```
template<typename _Ty>
class matrix {
    // used to enabled [][] overload on matrix objects
    class proxy_row_vector {
    public:
        proxy_row_vector(std::vector<_Ty>& _vec, std::size_t _cols, std::size_t _row_index) 
            : vec(_vec), cols(_cols), row_index(_row_index) {}
        const _Ty& operator[](std::size_t col_index) const {
            return vec[row_index*cols + col_index];
        }
        _Ty& operator[](std::size_t col_index) {
            return vec[row_index*cols + col_index];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<_Ty>& vec;
        std::size_t cols;
        std::size_t row_index;
    };
public:
    matrix(std::size_t _rows, std::size_t _cols) 
        : mtx(_rows*_cols), rows(_rows), cols(_cols) {}
    proxy_row_vector operator[](std::size_t row_index) const {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, cols, row_index);
    }
    proxy_row_vector operator[](std::size_t row_index) {
        return proxy_row_vector(mtx, cols, row_index);
    }
    std::vector<_Ty>::const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return mtx.cbegin();
    }
    std::vector<_Ty>::const_iterator cend() const {
        return mtx.cend();
    }
    // ... other iterator access methods ...
private:
    std::vector<_Ty> mtx;
    std::size_t rows;
    std::size_t cols;
};
```

Then you can create a 2D array simply and manipulate elements using indexing or iterators as follows:

```
matrix<int> m(3,3); // default initialises 3x3 matrix of ints
m[0][0] = 1; // set first row, first column element to 1
for (auto& el : m) 
    el = 4; // fill m with value 4
```

The advantage of this approach is simple iterator support allowing you to use any of the standard algorithms to manipulate the matrix elements as well as providing a convenient, managed interface for any 2D array of elements.

Note: The above class `matrix` is very minimal and you'd obviously want to provide further methods and constructors (such as `at` methods for bounds-checking, as well as a `rows()` method and `columns()` method for finding the number of rows, columns of the matrix, respectively).